# como omito el "\" en una sentencia sqlconnection (visual studio)

Tags: c#

Quiero agregar esta sentencia y justo despues del VP-PC ese "\" me sale error.

```
   SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("server=VP-PC\SQLEXPRESS;DataBase=Negocios2017; uid=sa; pwd=sql");
```

Como podría hacer para que lo reconozca como el nombre de mi server y no como código

Comment: ¿Si escapas el carácter "\"? En muchos lenguajes se deben escapar ciertos caractéres debido a que forman parte de la nomenclatura especial. Si mal no recuerdo, y si estás trabajando en ambiente `.Net`, debes escapar el carácter de la siguiente manera: `server=VP-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;`. Como puedes ver escribo dos veces el carácter: `\\`. Prueba eso y comenta los resultados. Saludos

Comment: Lo otro que puedes hacer es poner un arroba (@) justo antes de las comillas dobles de la cadena de conexión, de esa forma indicas que debe tomar la cadena de forma textual, y ya no tienes que "escapar" tus caracteres especiales.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El caracter `\` es el caracter de *escape* en c# y otros lenguajes con sintaxis derivada de c.

Esto significa que el procesador o compilador va a darle un tratamiento especial cada vez que encuentre un `\` dentro de una cadena de caracteres. Este tratamiento especial consiste en básicamente *ver* el o los caracteres que siguen para *empotrar* algún caracter especial dentro de de la cadena. Por ejemplo, `\r` introduce un *retorno de carro* `CR`, mientras que `\n` un *avance de línea* `LF` y `\r\n` —la combinación de estos— que es el equivalente, en Windows, a la tecla <kbd>Enter</kbd> (`CRLF`).

Dicho esto, para introducir una diagonal inversa, se utiliza una de las siguientes secuencia de escape:

- `\\` (doble diagonal inversa).
- `\u005c`, una secuencia de escape con el código Unicode correspondiente a `\`

Otra manera de hacerlo, en c#, es anteponer un caracter `@` a la cadena de caracteres. De esta manera, el compilador tomará todo lo escrito como literal (sin procesar secuencias de escape):

```
String miCadena = @"\hola\r\n";
```

De esta manera, la cadena es tal como se ve, sin ningún tipo de *interprete* sobre lo que contiene.

Para más información sobre secuencias de escape y strings en general te recomiendo leer [Strings in C# and .NET](https://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Strings) (en Inglés).